# nth-child(1) affect to all DIVs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I use `soc-box:nth-child(1) {background-color : red}` OR `.container-soc:nth-child(1) {background-color : red}`, it applies to all divs, but I want it to just apply to the first div.

It happened when I wrapped an `<a>` tag around my divs.

```css
.container-soc:nth-child(1) {background-color : red}
```

```html
 <div class="soc-box">
 
   <a href="http://sample.com">
      <div class='container-soc'>
      <img src="img/tel.svg" class='iconDetails' >
        <div class="texti">
     <h4>Item 1</h4>
     </div>
    </div>
   </a>

  <a href="http://sample.com">
    <div class='container-soc'>
     <img src="img/twitter.svg" class='iconDetails' >
      <div class="texti">
      <h4>Item 2</h4>
     </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 
</div>
```

Comment: `nth-child()` ist only possible for child elements on the same level (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: `.container-soc:nth-child(1)`  this will select every `.container-soc` that is the first child of it's parent

Comment: @Alexander it's fine to include div inside a .. there is nothing *wrong* doing this, it may simply look not as intended if we don't write the correct CSS

Comment: @Alexander right, i fix it in question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I'm sorry. You are right. The W3C validator agrees with you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you are testing if `container-soc` is the first child of its parent element, which it is .

Instead, you should select based on the `a` tags.

```css
.soc-box a:nth-of-type(1) .container-soc {background-color: red}
```

```html
<div class="soc-box">
  <a href="http://sample.com">
      <div class='container-soc'>
        <img src="img/tel.svg" class='iconDetails'>
        <div class="texti">
          <h4>Item 1</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
  </a>
  <a href="http://sample.com">
     <div class='container-soc'>
        <img src="img/twitter.svg" class='iconDetails'>
        <div class="texti">
          <h4>Item 2</h4>
       </div>
     </div>
  </a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`:nth-child(x)` takes every `x`-th of the parent, which is in the case of one is every element.

In the case of two, it would be every second element.

`:first-child` would work as a selector

```css
.soc-box a:first-child .container-soc {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="soc-box">

  <a href="http://sample.com">
    <div class='container-soc'>
      <img src="img/tel.svg" class='iconDetails'>
      <div class="texti">
        <h4>Item 1</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://sample.com">
    <div class='container-soc'>
      <img src="img/twitter.svg" class='iconDetails'>
      <div class="texti">
        <h4>Item 2</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: when i use `.container-soc:first-child` get same result as `.container-soc:nth-child(1)`

Comment: I put an example in there with working `:first-child`

Comment: thanks,but i think there is no difference to use `first-child` or `nth-child(1)`, the correct solution focus over select right selector, in this case (`<a>`)